# Mongoose project date conditions between dates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting a count of objects that were created between two dates inside an `aggregate` query. Below is how my aggregate query looks like with the `project` in question specified.

```
DataTable.aggregate([
    { $match: { ... } },
    { $lookup: { ... },
    { $project: { ... },
    { $match: { ... },
    {
      $project: {
          count: {$sum: {'$cond': [{ '$gte': ['date', '$someOldDate'], '$lte': ['date', someNewDate] }, 1, 0]} }
      }
    }
])
```

Here's the error thrown by `Mongoose`

`MongoError: An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gte: [ "date", "$someOldDate" ], $lte: [ "date", new Date(1496772810338) ] }`

Comment: Couple of things incorrect here. You need `$group` for counting objects and use explicit `$and` to get the $lte and $gte comparison on the same field. So replace `$project` with  `{
      $group: {
          _id:null,
          count: {$sum: {'$cond': [{$and:[{ '$gte': ['$date', someOldDate]}, {'$lte': ['$date',someNewDate] }]}, 1, 0]} }
      }
    }`

Comment: Thank you! `$and` is what I was really missing. The `$project` works fine as is for my use case as the `$group` comes in much later. Happy to accept your answer if you'd like to post this comment as an answer. Thanks again!